# Feature Toggles for Front-end Redesign

Tags: deployment, ui, continuous-delivery

We are planning a redesign of our front-end and would like to roll it out using a [feature toggle](http://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html). We want to expose the changes to limited sets of users as we iterate and perhaps allow users to opt into the new design. I have seen this done on a number of sites, but am having trouble finding details on how this sort of toggle is implemented.

The redesign will touch most of our HTML and CSS. Some views will disappear entirely, new ones will be added, and others will simply be changed. The JS will remain largely the same, as will the backend code. We use Angular and Node (sails/express).

**How is this sort of "brand new UI" feature toggle typically implemented?**

Here are two general approaches we're considering, though we're not really happy with either:

- Have two separate asset folders, one for the old design and one for the new design. Serve up assets from the appropriate folder based on a server-side toggle. Each time a view template is requested, the toggle would be checked and the appropriate view returned.
- Perform the toggling client-side. Namespace the new CSS under a class that we would apply to the document body based on the toggle. We could link to either old or new pages based on the toggle. Or if the page is in both the old and new design, we could render the view differently based on the toggle.

The first approach would essentially double the size of our client directory and entail a number of duplicate files. If we make updates to files that exist in both the old and new version while we roll out the new design, we'd have to make them in both places. But it feels like the second approach introduces a lot of complexity and would be difficult to clean up once the rollout is complete. Very interested in what alternatives are out there, or modifications to either of these approaches.

Comment: https://github.com/mjt01/angular-feature-flags

Comment: For the backend, I believe you should manage a FeatureFlag service within your system yourself - they're not rocket science. However there are plenty of cases where you should probably use an independent FeatureFlag SaaS product that lets your Sales team control such flags. Remember, these flags need to be tested in your Testing environment still before going into Production, to ensure the FeatureFlag itself doesn't break other customer's who are configured with that flag to be "off".